# How do I remove the "remembered password" on a luks usb drive? (22.04)

Tags: files, encryption, luks

I have a USB drive which I encrypted with luks.

My Ubuntu machine is set to decrypt and open it without prompting for a password (As I have previously selected the "remember password" prompt).

I'd like to change it back to having it ask for the password each time.

How do I do this?

Comment: How did you set it up to remember the password? Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I've updated the original question with the information you are asking for. Ubuntu prompted me as to how I wanted to handle the password in future, to which I selected something like "remember password". It is this that I want to undo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is saved with [Gnome Keyring](https://help.gnome.org/users/seahorse/stable/keyring.html.en).

You can see and delete the keys with the app "Passwords and Keys" a.k.a. Seahorse under *Passwords* -> *Login*:

[image: Encryption passphrase in seahorse]